# Remodel Recessed Lighting in New Basement?

Tags: lighting, basement, recessed-lighting

I am finishing my basement and will be installing a drop ceiling.  Right now the ceiling is open.  I purchased some recessed lighting on clearance at Home Depot for $5.00, normally $20.  After doing some research online, it seems that I should not use them on my open ceiling.  Most people say that "new construction" lighting should be used.  So, my question is, because I got such a good deal on these lights, is there any way I can use them?  I purchased some hangers, but I'm not sure if the remodel lights will attach to them.  Thanks for any help.

Corey

Answer (score 1):

Remodel recessed lighting can be installed on drop ceiling tiles - I have done this a few times.  You can cut out holes and install them from an adjacent tile.  The install is pretty easy - but your drop ceiling has to be properly installed so it can take the extra weight.  If you have problems installing on your drop ceiling just ask on here.